# Messenger disappears from bundle onCreate

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Messenger as an IPC mechanism between my appwidget and an activity.

I do the following:
I create an intent that starts a specific activity when a button is clicked on my appwidget.

```
intent = new Intent(mContext, TorchLightActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(RPC, new Messenger(mHandler));
intent.putExtra(TYPE, mType);
...
final PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(layout, actionPendingIntent);
```

When I click on my widget button an activity is started

```
onCreate(...)
final Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
// Get null here
mMessanger = (Messenger) bun.get(FlashlightModule.RPC); 
// Working great
mType = bun.getInt(FlashlightModule.Type);
```

When looking at the bundle I can see that the only extra data I have is `FlashlightModule.Type` e.g. the int value.

The intent is created with extras from the start (see [Get the intent from onCreate in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637453/get-the-intent-from-oncreate-in-android) ) and setData is used from the start (see [Application widget with bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663242/application-widget-with-bundle))

Is it possible at all to pass Messenger between AppWidget to my own activity?

Thank you.

Comment: I found out a weird behavior, maybe someone can shed light on it. I'm using setData on the intent to differentiate it from similar intents (I'm using the same activity, but with different extras). When removing setData suddenly the parcel is passed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to use Messenger as an IPC mechanism between my appwidget and an activity.

This makes no sense.

Your `AppWidgetProvider` instance will live for a couple of milliseconds -- any longer, and you're doing it wrong. It will never have an opportunity to use "IPC" with your activity, via `Messenger` or any other means.

Moreover, you should never create something from a `BroadcastReceiver` (such as an `AppWidgetProvider`) that you are expecting to live past the end of `onReceive()` (on `onUpdate()` for the `AppWidgetProvider`), such as your `Handler`, let alone the `Messenger`.

When your activity wishes to update the app widget's UI, it can create the `RemoteViews` and update the app widget.

Comment: I didn't explain myself well enough. The object that receives the message lives as part of a static object, therefore it lives as long as the process lives. The AppWidget BroadcastReceiver in my case does nothing.

Comment: @EfiMK: "The object that receives the message lives as part of a static object, therefore it lives as long as the process lives" -- but then you certainly do not need a `Handler` or `Messenger`. Just call a method on the "static object" when you need to talk to it.

Comment: Agree, sometimes you need someone else to tell you the obvious. But do you know why the parcel wasn't part of the extras?

Comment: @EfiMK: My best guess is that it is because you are not using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when creating the `PendingIntent`, and there was already a `PendingIntent` outstanding for your same `Intent` routing information (e.g., action, component) but with an older set of extras. If you are using `PendingIntent` with `Intents` with extras, you always need to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, or kin when creating the `PendingIntent`.