# Retrieving intent extras from widget

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I'm making a widget for my `WebView` app, and it's got a list of buttons on it. Currently, It's firing an intent whenever their pressed. In that intent, I'm putting some string extra's, but when the `onNewIntent` receives the intent, the value for the extra is `NULL`. So I'm stuck on receiving the actual string extra.

Here's the code on my list provider:

```
override fun getViewAt(positionIndexNum: Int): RemoteViews {

    ........

    val extrasObj = Bundle()
    extrasObj.putString("shortcutUrl", listViewUrlArr[positionIndexNum]) // I've tried hardcoding this part and it still returns null.
    extrasObj.putString("shortcutJs", listViewJsArr[positionIndexNum])
    extrasObj.putString("shortcutId", listViewIdArr[positionIndexNum])
    val fillInIntentObj = Intent()
    fillInIntentObj.putExtras(extrasObj)
    viewObj.setOnClickFillInIntent(listViewItemId, fillInIntentObj)
    return viewObj
}
```

Here's the code from the `onNewIntent` function:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intentObj: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intentObj)
    val bundle = intentObj.extras
    if (bundle != null) {
        for (key in bundle.keySet()) {
            Log.e("TAG", key + " : " + if (bundle[key] != null) bundle[key] else "NULL")
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

That outputs in the logcat:

```
shortcutUrl : NULL
shortcutId : NULL
shortcutJs : NULL
```

I've also tried: `intentObj.getStringExtra("shortcutId")` which still returns `NULL`

**EDIT:**

I also have this `PendingIntent` code in the `updateAppWidget` function:

```
    val clickIntent = Intent(contextObj, MainActivity::class.java)

    val clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(contextObj, 0,
    clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    viewsObj.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_list, clickPI)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found a fix for this, I'm not sure how it really works but I changed:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
```

to

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
```

in the `PendingIntent`. Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full answer which I posted on another question:
[Application widget with bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663242/application-widget-with-bundle/72799941#72799941)

**Read the Intent in MyActivity:**

```
private fun readIntent() {
    val intentExtras: Bundle? = intent.extras
    intentExtras?.let {
        val intentMessage: String? = intentExtras.getString(APPWIDGET_INTENT_MESSAGE)
        println(intentMessage)
    }
}
```

**Here is a method in Kotlin to get pending intent to open your activity**

```
fun getPendingIntentMyActivity(context: Context, message: String): PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
    intent.action = APPWIDGET_INTENT
    intent.data = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

    val extras = Bundle().apply {
        putString(APPWIDGET_INTENT, APPWIDGET_OPEN_APP)
        putString(APPWIDGET_INTENT_MESSAGE, message)
    }
    intent.putExtras(extras)
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
}
```

**Then set it in the Widget**

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rootView, getPendingIntentMyActivity(context, "Hello World")
```